# How to display specific K2 extra field of current item with k2 tool module

Tags: k2, sql, json

I am trying to display specific extra field values of a specific item with the K2 tool module.

I have tried to get just `BRAND`, but I'm getting **stdClass::brand()** error.

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$articleid = JRequest::getInt('id');
$db->setQuery('SELECT extra_fields FROM #__k2_items WHERE id='.$articleid);
$AllExtraFields = $db->loadResult();
$AllExtraFields = json_decode($AllExtraFields);
$lists[$i]->brand= $AllExtraFields[1]->value;
$myid=$lists[$i]->brand();
echo $myid;
```

**This is a row from my `#__k2_items` table:**

[image]

**This is the desired row from my `#__k2_extra_fields` table:**

[image: This view from item]

Comment: I deleted my anwser because I'm not sure but pelase take a look at this, may help you  [Display specific field](https://www.joomlaworks.net/forum/k2-en/29008-display-specific-extra-field-in-module-position),  [Get array from database](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JDatabaseDriver.html) and [Get JSON from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15006948/get-distinct-dates-from-json-array-joomla). Good luck.

Comment: @ThiagoGuimarães Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. I'm glad you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it like this and it works.

```
<?php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$articleid = JRequest::getInt('id');
$db->setQuery('SELECT extra_fields FROM #__k2_items WHERE id='.$articleid);
$AllExtraFields = $db->loadResult();
$AllExtraFields = json_decode($AllExtraFields);
echo $AllExtraFields[0]->value;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Start by extracting the `extra_fields` column's json string from `#__k2_items` table at the row of your choosing, then decode it.  Each row from the array (generated by decoding json), will have two elements having respective keys: `id` and `value` .

I don't quite know the full picture of what you are trying to do, but I can help you to relate and extract the data.

```
$output = [];
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$db->setQuery('SELECT extra_fields FROM #__k2_items WHERE id = ' . JRequest::getInt('id'));
foreach (json_decode($db->loadResult() ?: '[]', true) as ['id' => $id, 'value' => $value]) {
    
    // Access the extra_fields using this row's id
    $db->setQuery('SELECT * FROM #__k2_extra_fields WHERE id = ' . (int)$id);
    $row = $db->loadAssoc();
    $output[] = [
        'id' => $id,
        'value' => $value,
        'extraFieldName' => $row['name'],
        'extraFieldType' => $row['type'],
        'decoded' => json_decode($row['value'], true)
    ];
}
var_export($output);
```

This will effectively display the following:

```
[
    [
        'id' => '1',
        'value' => 'PERKINS',
        'extraFieldName' => 'BRAND',
        'extraFieldType' => 'textfield',
        'decoded' => [
            [
                'name' => null,
                'value' => '',
                'target' => null,
                'alias' => 'brand',
                'required' => 1,
                'showNull' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        'id' => '2',
        'value' => '14',
        // more data that I can't see...
    ],
]
```

I have seen snippets in K2 such as `$item->extra_fields = $model->getItemExtraFields($item->extra_fields, $item);` which indicate that there are some pre-existing helpful methods on offer, but I must admit that I am not a K2 user, so I am poorly suited to advise on these.

Comment: That's what made me confused when I tried to answer his question.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa. You answer is great as usual. But maybe this time you missed smth. Code display nothing. I coldn't find the problem.

Comment: Correct you are.  The problem is not in the code -- `value` is an empty string.  I have ported your data to a demo script for you to see for yourself.  https://3v4l.org/jXGMH  What value were you expecting to see displayed? @oki

Comment: Ok. You are right that value is empty. But value that we are looking for is under item's table. How can we display it as "brand" value? Im sorry maybe i can't see your point.

Comment: I had completely confused myself about the table structures.  I have completely rewritten my answer.  Let me know if there is something remaining to fix up. @oki

Comment: @mickmackusa thank you so much.